# Dynamic Ionic Items / Inputs

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, dynamic

I'm in the process of learning the ionic framework. I'm building a JSON to form system, I know there's some packages out there that handle this however I'd like to build a simple one. It works great at the moment, however I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically choose which inputs I'm going to use. Ideally I'd be able to define the input within the html tag such as:  however this doesn't seem to be the case.

I've worked around this by using ngIf statements as you can see below:

```
    <ion-card *ngFor="let gf of generatedForm">
      <h1>{{gf.slug}}</h1>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{gf.data.label}}</ion-label>
        <ng-container *ngIf="gf.data.type === 'select'">
          <ion-select multiple={{gf.data.multiple}} placeholder="Select One">
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let gfs of gf.schema.enum" value={{gfs}}>{{gfs}}</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="gf.data.type === 'textarea'">
          <ion-label position="floating">Description</ion-label>
          <ion-textarea></ion-textarea>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="gf.data.type !== 'textarea' || gf.data.type !== 'select'">
          <ion-input type={{gf.data.type}}></ion-input>
        </ng-container>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card>
```

Like I said, it works fine but I really don't like how I'm doing this and was wondering if there was a more refined way of doing it, rather than if statements for each type of input tag. Tags like text, date and time work within the `<ion-input-type="type>` tag which is great, but as textarea and select are different tags it can't be done via that.

So, is there a way I can refine this? Sorry if I'm missing the obvious, I'm just rattling my brain here. The page's typescript file is using a service I built to format the JSON data I'm pulling and returning it, so I can add certain fields and  manipulate that data if needed. I wont post that code here, but the data I can use includes options like, input type, required, label, multiple choice etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component for each choice after that you can create them dynamically from the typescript file.
This can be implemented using `ComponentFactoryResolver`

Typescript

```
import { ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentFactory } from '@angular/core';
...//Components imports.

@ViewChild("container", { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) container;
// Every type is mapped to a component reference
component = {
    'text': TextComponent,
    'number': NumberComponent,
    'hidden': HiddenComponent,
    'date': DateComponent,
    'text_area': TextAreaComponent,
    'relationship': DropdownComponent,
    'select_dropdown': TextComponent,
    'file': FileComponent,
    'checkbox': CheckboxComponent,
    'select': DropdownComponent,
    'offerItems': OfferItemsComponent,
    'password':PasswordComponent,
  }
      constructor( private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
      createComponent(type) {
        const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component[type]);
        this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
      }
```

So you need to loop on your data and every time you need to call the function.

html

```
<div #container>
    <template>
    </template>
</div>
```